# How to take all files from a folder as input (one at a time) and save them into another folder after processing?

Tags: python, r, bash

I have a `.py` script which takes one `.csv` at a time and pre-process it. I am running the bash command in this way:

`python3 cleaning_script.py file1.csv results_file1.csv`. It works completely fine. There are 300+ files in a folder which I have to pre-process, is there a better way (Loop maybe, but I don't know how to use loop in this environment) in which I can mention the folder and each file is taken as input from the source folder and pre-processed files is saved in the destination folder?

Because of the non-administrative rights in the system (Windows 10), I am using Rstudio terminal to execute my bash command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with bash, if there's not a massive number of files then you can use a glob:

```sh
for file in path/to/dir/*.csv
do
    python3 cleaning_script.py "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/result_$(basename "$file")"
done
```

Comment: This is probably the simplest solution. If you want to find all *.csv files in "dir" and it's subdirectories use `path/to/dir/**/*.csv`.

Comment: It seems like the simplest solution. However, I am really a beginner to this :( and I am unable to run this command. I am running this: ```C:\Users\AneesBaqir\Downloads\Final>for file in C:/Users/AneesBaqir/Downloads/Final/files/timeline/*.csv do python3 cleaning_script.py "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/result_$(basename "$file")" done``` and I am getting this message **file was unexpected at this time.**. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: @AneesBaqir Were you looking for a PowerShell solution? In WSL bash the paths would be more like `/mnt/c/Users/...`

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how this would work. I am just trying to do what you suggested in my RStudio terminal using my Windows 10 system.

Comment: If you're already located in the directory that contains the CSV files and you also want to generate the processed files there, then you can just do `for file in *.csv; do python3 cleaning_script.py "$file" "result_$file"; done`; that is, if your RStudio Terminal is really `bash`

Comment: I am doing it exactly you suggested, but it gives me the message ```file was unexpected at this time.```

Comment: That means that you're not using bash but PowerShell or DOS. Please re-tag your question so you can get an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this function from ["os" module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)! `os.listdir(path='.')` returns list of all entities at "path", this includes files and other directories. If you want to recursively loop through all entities of directory look at `os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)! it's a little more complicated but more powerfull.